# C macro with case statement to compose function name

Tags: c, macros

I'd like to have a macro that constructs a function name depending on its arguments, like:

```
#define CASE1 1
#define CASE2 2
#define CASE3 3

#define MYFNAME(c, s1, s2) \
   switch(c) \
   { case 1: s1 ## _case1_ ## s2; \
     case 2: s1 ## _case2_ ## s2; \
     case 3: s1 ## _case3_ ## s2; }

get_case1_val() { ... }
get_case2_val() { ... }
get_case3_val() { ... }

int main()
{
   MYFNAME(1, get, val)(); // would call get_case1_val();
...
...
}
```

The problem is, that it looks like that the macro appends ; at the
end of the composed string, and it pre-compiles it into:

```
get_case1_val;();
```

Any idea how to avoid getting ; at the end of concatenated string?

Thanks

Comment: Then get rid of the semicolons in the #define after `s2`

Comment: Tried already, but that generates error:
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
    { case1: s1 ## _case1_ ## s2 }

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to use a case *statement* as an *expression*.  This is possible in some programming languages, such as Lisp and Rust, but not in C.  You can instead write something like

```
#define CALL_MYFNNAME(c, s1, s2, ...) do { \
switch(c) \
{ case 1: s1 ## _case1_ ## s2 (__VA_ARGS__); break; \
  case 2: s1 ## _case2_ ## s2 (__VA_ARGS__); break; \
  case 3: s1 ## _case3_ ## s2 (__VA_ARGS__); break; } } while (0)
```

which puts the actual function call inside the switch.  I've made some other minor corrections.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect in the expansion. I ran this through the VS preprocessor to double check i had it right.  It expands to this, which you can see why it fails.

```
switch(1) { case 1: get_case1_val; case 2: get_case2_val; case 3: get_case3_val; }();
```

properly formatted

```
switch(1) { 
  case 1: get_case1_val;
  case 2: get_case2_val;
  case 3: get_case3_val; }();
```

You likely intended to do something more like this, using a variadic macro.

```
#define MYFNAME(c, s1, s2, ...) \
switch(c) \
{ case 1: s1 ## _case1_ ## s2(__VA_ARGS__); break; \
  case 2: s1 ## _case2_ ## s2(__VA_ARGS__); break; \
  case 3: s1 ## _case3_ ## s2(__VA_ARGS__); break;  }

MYFNAME(1, get, val, list_of, arguments); // would call get_case1_val(list_of, arguments);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. I also up voted @zwol sinec both answer my problem. Thank you both!

Comment: This code expends functions, what about variables? I did something like: `#define MYVAR(p, s1, s2) (p==1 ? s1 ## _case1_ ## s2 : p==2 ? s1 ## _case2_ ## s2 : s1 ## _case3_ ## s2)`. It works, but is that how it should be done?

Comment: How it should be done? Almost certainly not. I'm fairly proficient and it took me a minute to figure out how/ why that works. When you code, don't be clever unless there's a really good reason. I'd hate to have to read code written that way, and you aren't accomplishing anything that you couldn't with a simple to read switch statement.

Comment: Thanks, you are probably right. I actually wanted to get rid of switch statements and make shorter code, but it looks like those macros are not something that would help.

Comment: Your suggested solution at a minimum requires `break;`'s (else you're just falling through).